# How can I change Firefox window.location.hash without creating a page reload?

Tags: javascript

I'm storing some state information in the URL fragment (hash, whatever you call it).  When I change the `window.location.hash` in Chrome, and Safari the page doesn't reload - this is the behavior I want.  When I change `window.location.hash` in Firefox, I get a page reload.  How do I prevent this?

*Note: My reason for storing state in the URL is so that userA can send the url to userB and userB will be able so see the same page (loaded by AJAX).*

---

Resolution: For what it's worth, in Firefox (only?) the page will reload if you completely remove the hash including the "#" character.  I ended up just making sure not to delete the entire hash.

Comment: using `preventDefault` ?

Comment: I would recommend finding another way to store/cache state information rather than using `window.location` method such as in a _cookie_ or _javascript `var`_.

Comment: You may need to provide more information and a test page.  I have never seen this behavior in Firefox.  For example, use FF to go to http://unicodinator.com/ and click any character -- you should see the hash change but no page reload (at least, this is what happens on all machines I've tested, with FF 4 and FF 3.6).  This uses document.location.hash to change the hash.

Comment: @pixelbobby see note in post above

Comment: yeah, that is a pretty cool effect.  I see what you're trying to do; it's `bookmark` more or less.  I checked the code in chrome debugger.  I'll put a post below.

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery plugin called `history` that does this. I suggest you look at the source code (it's not very big last time I checked). It also works for older versions of IE but it's really nasty :P

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good article about History API here: http://blog.webspecies.co.uk/2011-05-26/html5-history-api-dynamic-websites-like-never-before.html
That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the behavior of Firefox (to reload the page even when only changing the hash part) and it cannot be overridden, perhaps you could instead write a custom solution which [finds the (x,y) position of the anchor target](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) and call [`window.scroll(x,y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.scroll).

Answer (score 1):

On the post you mentioned, here's the code that sets the `hash`:

```
function (hsh) {
    hsh="#"+hsh;
    this.current.hash=hsh;
    document.location.hash=hsh;
}
```

And here's the code that reads the `hash` *(e.g. from another URL)*:

```
function () {
    if(document.location.hash.split("#").pop()==this.current.hash.split("#").pop()) { return; }//this hash was set by code!
    var bl=-1;//-1 = none; otherwise, it's a block index.
    var cp=-1;
    if(document.location.hash.indexOf(Un.HASH_BLOCK_PREFIX)&gt;-1) {
        var blkhsh=document.location.hash.substring(Un.HASH_BLOCK_PREFIX.length+1);
        var blknum=parseInt(blkhsh,16);
        if(!isNaN(blknum)) {
            for(bi in Un.BLOCKS.blFrom) {
                if(Un.BLOCKS.blFrom[bi]==blkhsh) {
                    bl=bi; break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            var blkspc=blkhsh.split(Un.HASH_BLOCK_SPACE).join(" ");
            for(bi in Un.BLOCKS.blName) {
                if(Un.BLOCKS.blName[bi]==blkspc) {
                    bl=bi; break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if(document.location.hash!="") {
        var hexhsh=document.location.hash.split("#").pop().split(Un.HASH_CP_PREFIX).pop().split("x").pop(); //if the cp_prefix is missing, or if prefixed with x, this will still work :)
        if(hexhsh.length==4 && !isNaN(parseInt(hexhsh,16))) {
            cp=hexhsh;
            for(bi in Un.BLOCKS.blFrom) {
                if(Un.BLOCKS.blFrom[bi]&gt;cp) {
                    bl=bi-1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(bl&gt;-1) {
        Un.selectBlock(bl,(cp==-1 ? 0 : 1));
    }
    else {
        Un.next(1);
        Un.setMenuButton($("#BlockButton"),0);
    }
    if(cp!=-1) {
        setTimeout("Un.cpOpen('"+cp+"')",100);
    }
}
```