# Removing hash from URL

Tags: jquery, browser, cross-browser

After removing hash from URL using `window.location.hash=''` page getting reloaded in firefox.

**EDIT**

Example:

`wwww.Mysite.come/#page=1`

On a click of button I am removing hash value using following code

`window.location.hash=''`

After removing the hash page is getting reloaded in firefox.

I don't want to reload page I just want to remove hash from URL

How to fix it?

Comment: I am sorry but your question doesn't make sense. Can you please clarify and show some code examples?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the hash?

Comment: I submit ajax form and part of the page is getting change.. after this step that hash value does not make sense that is why I want to remove it

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269044/remove-fragment-in-url-with-javascript-w-out-causing-page-reload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location:

> Examples
>
> Whenever a property of the location object is modified, a document
>   will be loaded using the URL as if window.location.assign() had been
>   called with the modified URL.

This question I think addresses what you want using jQuery:

[Change hash without reload in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939041/change-hash-without-reload-in-jquery)

Other related questions:

[Change the URL in the browser without loading the new page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript)

[How to remove the hash from window.location with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh)

[How can I change Firefox window.location.hash without creating a page reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312518/how-can-i-change-firefox-window-location-hash-without-creating-a-page-reload)

Answer (score 22):

Just in case somebody else is still looking for a solution to this. Try this when the page loads.

```
history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly,

```
<a href="#someElementID" id="myLinkName">Some Text</a>
```

clicking the above link in a browser normally results in an added hash in the address bar, like *www.websitename.com#someElementID* <- this is what you're looking to **prevent**, yes?

The solution I just tested which is working and DOES NOT refresh the page is:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This works in a 'click()' event that involves anchor tags that link to elements' id's, such as in the anchor tag example above. In action, it would look like this in your 'click()' event:

```
<script>
    $('#myLinkName').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        //the rest of the function is the same.
    });
</script>
```

Now, clicking on the same link leaves the address bar with the same URL www.websitename.com, WITHOUT the added hash from clicking the anchor.

Answer (score 2):

We can remove/escape from appending the hash by returning false in click function.

```
<script>
    $('#add_user').click(function(){       
     //your custom function code here..
    return false;
});
</script>

<a id="add_user" href="#">Add Card</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will find this example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section2) very useful for your need plus it gives you elegant scrolling move compatable with all browsers, check below code :

```
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

// Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
if (this.hash !== "") {

    // Prevent default anchor click behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Store hash
    var hash = this.hash;

    // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
    // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area

      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
       }, 800, function(){

      // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
      // obvously you will ignore this step because you want to remove the hash in first place - but just in case you want turn it on again

      window.location.hash = hash;
    });
   } // End if
  });
});
```