# Chrome: setting window.location.hash causes 'find in page' search box to go away

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome

When I set .hash, the little 'find in page' box disappears.  Any way to leave it open?

*Why am I setting .hash? Same reason as [How can I change Firefox window.location.hash without creating a page reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312518/how-can-i-change-firefox-window-location-hash-without-creating-a-page-reload) I want users to be able to bookmark cells they have selected.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome bug. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72504

Edit: looks like a *fixed* Chrome bug.