# window.location.hash = '' doesn't remove the hash itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the hash from window.location with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh)

When closing the slideshow I wan't the address to be back to normal but the "#" is still there, any way to overcome this?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508574/remove-hash-from-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location:

> Examples
>
> Whenever a property of the location object is modified, a document
>   will be loaded using the URL as if window.location.assign() had been
>   called with the modified URL.

This question I think addresses what you want using jQuery:

[Change hash without reload in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939041/change-hash-without-reload-in-jquery)

Other related questions:

[Change the URL in the browser without loading the new page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript)

[How to remove the hash from window.location with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh)

[How can I change Firefox window.location.hash without creating a page reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312518/how-can-i-change-firefox-window-location-hash-without-creating-a-page-reload)